# delete individual items of the array in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to delete individual items of the whole array in localStorage. Is it possible to achieve that. I tried the below code. But its deleting the whole watchlist. I have attached a image of the local storage elements

```
function removeFromWatchlist(par) {
  localStorage.removeItem("watchList")[par];
}
```

[SEE THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYoH1.png)

Comment: You should override the item with the correct value. You can't manipulate it directly like this. First read it, then modify it, then store it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why this is not working, you need to understand how JS will "read" this piece of code as it's being parsed from left to right:

```js
localStorage.removeItem("watchList")[par]
```

1. read the variable called `localStorage`
2. read the key `removeItem` from the above step
3. call the function from the above step with the argument `"watchList"`
4. access the key `[par]` from the return of the above step

The issue here is that on step 3, the entire value is removed from local storage *and* the function `removeItem` returns `undefined` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem#return_value).

To make it work, you should find an order of operations that fits your task: you want to modify a value in local storage, so you should:

1. get that value from localStorage
2. modify the value from above step
3. store the modified value in localStorage

Which in code would look something like

```js
const value = localStorage.getItem("watchList") // step 1
const modified = /* write your logic here */ // step 2
localStorage.setItem("watchList", modified) // step 3
```

---

Also, don't forget that what is stored into and obtained from localStorage is always a string. So if you're storing objects, you should `JSON.parse(value)` when reading them with `getItem` and `JSON.stringify(value)` when storing them with `setItem`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, but you need to update the actual stored value - in your example you are removing the entire stored array.

However it would depend on exactly what `par` is - as you have an array of objects you will have to decide what `equal` means.

For example.

```
function removeFromWatchlist(par) {
  const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('watchList'));
  const test = JSON.stringify(par);
  const result = list.filter(x => JSON.stringify(x) === test);
  localStorage.setItem('watchList', JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

This would remove all occurrences of whatever `par` is from the array stored as `watchList` in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

The **removeItem()** method would remove the whole items of your watchList in local storage, but instead you can **find the index** of par parameter you are passing and update your watchList array and update it using **setItem()**.

```
const watchList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('watchList')) || [];
const index = watchList.findIndex(item => item.imdbId === par.imbdId); // in your case imbdId is unique value

if(index !== -1) {
    watchList.splice(index, 1); // removes the item from watchList based on the index
    localStorage.setItem('watchList', JSON.stringify(watchList)); // updateing new watchList
}
```